# Taking 5 seconds to shutdown a java grpc ManagedChannel

Tags: java, grpc

I have a client that needs to disconnect from one server and connect to another. Its taking about 16 seconds. I still haven't debugged the connection logic, but I can see the shutdown of the channel is taking 5 seconds. Is this expected behavior, or should I be looking for thread starvation in  my code.

```
LOG.debug("==============SHUTTING DOWN MANAGED CHANNEL");
long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(20, SECONDS);
long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
LOG.debug("Time to shutdown channel ms = {}",endTime-startTime);
LOG.debug("==============RETURN FROM SHUTTING DOWN MANAGED CHANNEL");
```

From the log

```
2018-07-09 14:41:23,143 DEBUG [com.ticomgeo.ftc.client.FTCClient] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-singleThreaded-Thread-1) ==============SHUTTING DOWN MANAGED CHANNEL 
2018-07-09 14:41:28,151 INFO  [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl] (grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1) [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl-1] Terminated 
2018-07-09 14:41:28,152 DEBUG [com.ticomgeo.ftc.client.FTCClient] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-singleThreaded-Thread-1) Time to shutdown channel ms = 5009 
2018-07-09 14:41:28,152 DEBUG [com.ticomgeo.ftc.client.FTCClient] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-singleThreaded-Thread-1) ==============RETURN FROM SHUTTING DOWN MANAGED CHANNEL
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two shutdown functions, shutdown and shutdownNow.  Is there any chance you have a calls going that are blocking shutdown?  You may be better served by shutdownNow.

**shutdown**

Initiates an orderly shutdown in which preexisting calls continue but new calls are rejected.

**shutdownNow**

Initiates a forceful shutdown in which preexisting and new calls are rejected. Although forceful, the shutdown process is still not instantaneous; isTerminated() will likely return false immediately after this method returns.